# Read and Writing from a text file with user requests

Tags: python, text-files

I have a code that opens the text file and asks the user if they want to type in a gtin-8 product code. But i can't find the total costs of the product. Any help would be highly appreciated! Here is my text file and code...

Text File:

```
gtin8   name    cost
34512340    plain brackets  £0.50
56756777    100 mm bolts    £0.20
90673412    L-shaped brackets   £1.20
76842309    Screwdriver £3.00
89432106    Radiator Key    £4.00
34267891    Panel Saw   £12.00
67532189    Junior Hacksaw  £7.00
98123470    Wrench  £8.00
18653217    Shovel  £8.00
67543891    Hammer  £10.00
23879462    File    £7.00
```

My Code:

```
loop = True
productsfile = open("Products.txt", "r+")
recieptfile = open("Receipt.txt", "w")
search = productsfile.readlines()
while True:
        yesno = input("Would you like to type in a gtin-8 product code?(yes/no)" )
        if yesno == "yes":
             gtin8 = int(input("Please enter your GTIN-8 code: "))
             if len(gtin8) == 8:
                     while True:
                             for line in search:
                                     if gtin8 in line:
                                             productline = line
                                             recieptfile = open("Receipt.txt", "w") 
                                             recieptfile.writelines("\n" + "+")
                                             quantity = int(input("What is the quantity of the product you require? "))
                                             itemsplit = productline.split(",") 
                                             cost = float(itemsplit[3]) 
                                             totalcost = (cost)*(quantity) 
                                             recieptfile.writelines("Your total cost is: ", totalcost)
             else:
                     print("Here is your reciept", "reciept.txt", "r")
```

Comment: `if len(gtin8) == 8:` can't be right since `gtin` is an integer.

Comment: That problem is not fixed but it's giving me an error saying this... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Year 10-11\Computing\A453\Controlled Assessment Task 2\Controlled Assessment Code.py", line 17, in <module>
    cost = float(itemsplit.split(","))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed up your script such that it is more readable and clear.  Basically it will continue to ask for products until you don't want to add any more.  It also check if the product exists or not. It stores the products and their prices in a dictionary.

```
recieptfile = open("Receipt.txt", "w")
product_lines = open("Products.txt", "r").readlines()
products = [i.split() for i in product_lines][1:]
product_costs = dict()
for i in products:
    product_costs[i[0]] = float(i[-1][1:])

total_cost = 0
first_item = True
while True:
    yesno = input("Would you like to type in a gtin-8 product code?(yes/no)" )
    if yesno == "yes":
        gtin8 = input("Please enter your GTIN-8 code: ")
        if gtin8 in product_costs:
            quantity = int(input("What is the quantity of the product you require? "))
            price = product_costs[gtin8]
            cost = price * quantity 

            if not first_item:
                recieptfile.write("\t+\n") 
            recieptfile.write("{0}\t{1}".format(gtin8, cost))
            total_cost += cost
            first_item = False
        else:
            print("Product not found")
    else:
        recieptfile.write("\nYour total cost is: {0}".format(total_cost))
        break
recieptfile.close()
with open('Receipt.txt', 'r') as recieptfile:
    print("Here is your reciept:")
    print(recieptfile.read())
```

Comment: Appreciate your help!